# How to make a form ShowDialog() itself in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How would you make an instance of a form open itself in a `Modal` way?

I tried `this.ShowDialog()` but it doesn't make the form appear modal (you can still access other forms). I guess this is because it is it's own parent form in if it shows itself, but I'm not sure.

My problem:

I have an application made of 2 forms:

1. `MainForm`
2. `LoginForm`

`MainForm` creates an instance of and opens `LoginForm` to ask the user to authenticate. `LoginForm` has a timer to regularly check and log the user in - I want this timer to open `LoginForm` modally. I know this could be achieved by putting the timer in `MainForm` but I would like to know how to make a form `ShowDialog()` an instance of itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From my experience `ShowDialog` does not let you access other forms...

Comment: Can you show how are you doing this ? What do you do in `Application.Run` then ?

Comment: Why would you call `ShowDialog` inside form, which you want to show?

Comment: After user logins, your LoginForm will be destroyed. Where you suppose timer will run?

Comment: @Shai That's the idea, I effectively want to be able to change the read only property `this.Modal` to `true` to prevent access to other forms.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky An instance of the `LoginForm` is kept globally in `MainForm` to prevent a memory leak - hence the form is not destroyed.

Comment: @James setting `TopMost` to `true` *might* help you with this issue

Comment: @Shai Thanks for the suggestion, it's close but it would still let users interact with other forms.

Comment: @James another solution might be as follows: set the `opacity` of the form to 100%, set `TopMost` to `true`, and see if you can make something out of it. I somewhat doubt it's even possible, but it might give you a lead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call `ShowDialog` after `InitializeComponent`:

```
public newForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ShowDialog();
}
```

**MY TEST**

I made new class named `Form2`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        //this may not call in constractor 
        //InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowModalForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

and start it on main without any parent and it starts modally:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        new Form2().ShowModalForm();
        //Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I was calling `ShowDialog()` after `InitializeComponent()` and it still only effectively `Show()`s the form.

Comment: That works, super. Just realised my problem was probably down to the `ShowDialog()` being in a new thread *feeling dumb*. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Form won't be modal if it's a top-level window (has no parent). On the other hand, if your form will have other form as a parent, then it will open modally (blocking parent) on `.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: The form `LoginForm` does have a parent, it's not top level.

Answer (score 0):

Here is option for you - define `LoginExpired` event on your `LoginForm`. Raise this event on timer tick event handler:

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    public event EventHandler LoginExpired;

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnLoginExpired();
    }

    protected virtual void OnLoginExpired()
    {
        if (Visible)
            return; // if this form visible, then user didn't authenticate yet

        if (LoginExpired != null)
            LoginExpired(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }        
}
```

Then subscribe on this event on your `Main` method:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    using (LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm())
    {
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        loginForm.LoginExpired += new EventHandler(loginForm_LoginExpired);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}

static void loginForm_LoginExpired(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm)sender;
    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        throw new NotAuthenticatedException();
}
```